# Unknown command: 'update_search_field' with pgfulltext

Tags: python, django, postgresql, full-text-search

Following the instructions on https://github.com/linuxlewis/djorm-ext-pgfulltext I added a search_index to one of my existing PostgreSQL models, as follows:

```
search_index = VectorField()

objects = SearchManager(
    fields = ('materials','origin','style'),
    config = 'pg_catalog.english',
    search_field = 'search_index',
    auto_update_search_field = True
)
```

Using my virtual-env and having pgfulltext installed, with this version `djorm-ext-pgfulltext==0.9.3` according to `pip freeze`, I cd to the directory where `manage.py`is located. And tried to run:

```
./manage.py update_search_field app_name
```

Wich resulted in the following error:

> Unknown command: 'update_search_field' Type 'manage.py help' for
>   usage.

Am I missing something on how this command is used? Should I add the index directly to my db instance with `psql`? And if so, how could I achieve this?
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Unknown command"

...this usually means you forgot to add the app to your `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py

That's not surprising since it seems they forgot to mention that on the readme for the app, but you need something like:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ... (your existing apps)
    'djorm_pgfulltext',
)
```

Django needs to be told about the app in this way so that it knows to look for the `management/commands` directory in the app.

Comment: I should have checked that. Thank you so much !